# Ordinary Differential Equations by Tenenbaum and Pollard Exercise 2.12

Tags: calculus

I'm working my into Ordinary Differential Equations by Tenenbaum and Pollard. In Chapter 1: Basic Concepts, Exercise 2, problem 12, they state that a standard type of exercise in calculus is:

If $x^3+y^3-3xy=0$, then $3x^2+3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}-3x\frac{dy}{dx}-3y=0$

It's been quite awhile since I took calculus. I have brushed up on it with a few different books, but I can't make out how they derive the right hand side. And I can't find any problems or exercises that look like this. I'm assuming it has something to do with taking partial derivatives. Can someone explain how this is derived? Any insights would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Remember the **[chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)**
And notice that they use **[implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function)**
You can find a lot of examples of implicit differentiation in internet only searching in Google  as implicit differentiation examples, and that is also valid for the chain rule. I hope it help you, and if you have a specific question it is welcome in comments.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. It was the implicit differentiation that threw me off. I'll brush up on that.

Comment: You are welcome i am glad that it help you.